# How to access Sinatra params hash and set Sinatra session hash from Sequel model?

Tags: ruby, hash, sinatra, sequel

Basically I'm trying to port the code as seen here to Sinatra and Sequel: [How to use bcrypt() in your Rails application](https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby#how-to-use-bcrypt-in-your-rails-application)

As a matter of fact, I am trying to write simple signup and login methods in a Sequel User model, which currently looks like this:

```
require 'sequel'
require 'bcrypt'

USERNAME_REGEXP = /^(\w){1,32}$/

# This file is called user.rb and it contains the User class, adding custom
# behavior to 'users' dataset by following its business logic.
class User < Sequel::Model(:users)
  include BCrypt

  one_to_many :items
  one_to_many :reactions

  plugin :validation_helpers

  def validate
    super
    validates_unique(:username, :email)
    validates_presence([:username, :password, :email])
    validates_format(USERNAME_REGEXP, :username)
  end

  def password
    @password ||= Password.new(password_hash)
  end

  def password=(new_password)
    @password = Password.create(new_password)
    self.password_hash = @password
  end

  def signup(params = {})
    @user = User.new(username: params[:username], email: params[:email])
    @user.password = params[:password]
    @user.save
  end

  def login(params = {})
    @user = User.where(username: params[:username], delete: false).first
    if @user.password == params[:password]
      session[:user_id] = @user.id
      redirect to("/#{@user.username}")
    else
      redirect to('/login')
    end
  end
end
```

Then my Sinatra app.rb is requiring the Sequel User model - so my question is: can I access `params` and `session` hash this way, without requiring Sinatra in the model?

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Comment: `login` method does not belong to the model.

Comment: Hello @MladenJablanović, so both the `signup` and `login` methods should be handled in the Sinatra `app.rb` file as controller methods (or only `login`)? Thanks again!

Comment: Well, `signup` looks like a good candidate for a class method in the model, and `login` to controller.

Comment: You're gonna need to pass them as arguments if you want them in a model's functions. You still wouldn't be able to call `render`, though, because that's a method only defined for controllers.

Comment: Hello @maxpleaner, thank you for your comment! You mean passing both `params`and `session` hashes as arguments to `login`and `signup`model methods? But then it looks like I won't be able to use Sinatra's `redirect`helper method within `login` anyway, so all things considered @MladenJablanović's suggestion is probably better.

Comment: Neither suggestion is better, they're both true statements. It's true that you can't call "redirect" from a model. I'm just letting you know that you can pass `params` or `session` as arguments to a model's functions and read them there, if you wanted. Anyway, to keep it simple - methods which relate to HTTP request/response should be in controller. Models are for db-related stuff. You can call model methods from controllers, but not vice versa. It's possible to write most of your db-interaction stuff in controllers, but that's a less organized approach.